# ruby: get caller class

Tags: ruby, recursion

Hi I've some problems with a data structure.
Let's think about a man who has many children, but a child can only have one father. So the child knows his father and the father knows all his children.
I want to use the `to_s` method to create an answer depending on who is asking a class.
I've figured out that `caller` represents the actual stack. and I have to use it to generate this decision (seams perfect because no need of gems).

Whats the problem: I don't know how how to decide ho is calling, look at this classes:

```
class child
    ...
    def to_s
      str = "I'm "
      str += @first_name
      str += @last_name
      str += " my dad is"
      str += @father.to_s
    end
  end

 class dad
    ...
    def to_s
      str = "I'm "
      str += @first_name
      str += @last_name
      str += " my childs are"
      @kids.each{|child| str+= child.to_s}
    end
  end
```

If `child` calls `to_s` from a `dad` instance it should return only the name, the other way around if a `dad` calls one of his `child`’s instances it also should return the names. 
My origin problem is more complex, so in order to solve this I have to prevent an infinite recursion in a case like that.

How can I compare with the caller's class?

Comment: Implement a separate `name` method and use `"my dad is #{@father.name}"` and `"my childs are #{kids.map(&:name).join(', ')}"`

Comment: When calling the function, you can pass `self` as an argument, so that the callee has a reference to the caller

Answer (score 0):

How about just passing a father instance when creating its children?
The following is rough but it works.

```
class Child

  attr_accessor :father, :first_name, :last_name

  def initialize(father, first_name)
    @father = father
    @first_name = first_name
    @last_name = father.last_name
  end

  def to_s
    "I'm #{first_name} #{last_name} my dad is #{father.first_name} #{father.last_name}"
  end
end


class Dad

  attr_accessor :kids, :first_name, :last_name

  def initialize(first_name, last_name)
    @first_name = first_name
    @last_name = last_name
    @kids = []
  end

  def make_kid(first_name)
    kids << Child.new(self, first_name)
  end

  def to_s
    "I'm #{first_name} #{last_name} my childs are #{kids.map(&:first_name).join(', ')}"
  end
end

dad = Dad.new 'OShea', 'Jackson'
dad.make_kid 'Darrell'
dad.make_kid 'Tommy'

dad.to_s
# => "I'm OShea Jackson my childs are Darrell, Tommy"

dad.kids.first.to_s
# => "I'm Darrell Jackson my dad is OShea Jackson"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a parameter to break recursion:

```
def to_s skip_recursion=false
  return "#{first_name} #{last_name}" if skip_recursion
  # then goes as before
  # ...
  str += " my dad is"
  str += @father.to_s(true)
end
```

but this in fact will behave like a separate method `name`